# Based on picklist selection, how to display corresponding pageblock on vf page- can anyone check this

Tags: visualforce, picklist, rendered

```
    <apex:pageblocksection id="pb1" rendered="{!(employment == 'sal')}">
    <apex:inputtext label="salary" value="{!salEmp}"  />
    <apex:inputtext label="company" value="{!company}"/>
    </apex:pageblocksection>

    <apex:pageblockSection id="pb2" rendered="{!(employment == 'busi')}" >
    <apex:inputtext label="annual income" value="{!annualinc}"/>
    <apex:inputText label="business" value="{!busiEmp}"/>
     </apex:pageblockSection>
```

i create picklist values in apex class. in actionsupport which action attribute to call

```
<apex:selectlist size="1" value="{!employment}" > 
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!employments}"/> 
  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="pb1,pb2"/>
```

Comment: you'll need to include the picklist portion of the VF page and the actionsupport associated with it

Comment: i create picklist values in apex class. in actionsupport which action attribute to call<apex:selectlist size="1" value="{!employment}" >
           <apex:selectOptions value="{!employments}"/>
               <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  reRender="pb1,pb2"/>

Answer (score 2):

The likely reason you are having trouble is because when the page is initially rendered, both pageBlocks aren't shown because `{!employment}` is neither `sal` or `busi`. Hence the DOM is never created for the pageBlocks by VF.

This is a common mistake and covered well by the infamous Bob Buzzard post "[VisualForce Rerendering Woes](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/02/visualforce-re-rendering-woes.html)".

Change your VF markup as shown below so there is always something in the DOM when the page is initially rendered (i.e. the `apex:outputPanel`)

```
<apex:outputPanel id="pb1">
  <apex:pageblocksection  rendered="{!(employment == 'sal')}">
    <apex:inputtext label="salary" value="{!salEmp}"  />
    <apex:inputtext label="company" value="{!company}"/>
  </apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel id="pb2">
  <apex:pageblockSection  rendered="{!(employment == 'busi')}" >
   <apex:inputtext label="annual income" value="{!annualinc}"/>
   <apex:inputText label="business" value="{!busiEmp}"/>
 </apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>
```